# Concatenation of a Field Bidden using SQL adapter displayed in a sharepoint GridView

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sharepoint, web-parts

what I am doing is using SQL getting the column and then adding a new column to gridview, however because the text of this column is a lot, 
Here is the Code,

```
using sqldatasource(....)
public SPGridView gridview = new SPGridView();    
gridview .Columns.Add(bind.BuildBoundField("ColumnName", "Database ColumnName"));
```

Wonder if anyone knows how can I show reduced text from "Database ColumnName" to "ColumnName"
However I dont want to change the real text in the database.

Note: the column contains string of text data (more like a sentence)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am understanding correctly, do you want to show only a part of the text in the grid? 
If yes, you can use override the appropriate databound events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview_events.aspx and do the formatting.